# Number validation for a String using ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs

I need number validation for String (i.e) type="text"

```html
<input type="text" min="1" max="5" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" required />
```

Comment: What is wrong with your posted code ? I mean what change you want ?

Comment: If i give type="text" number validation is not working. I want to save the value as a string

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Is it not validating that only numbers are present or you want users to not to be able to type any other character into field ?

Comment: The user able to give character as input. But i want user to give only numbers without changing my input type="text"

Comment: You are going to need a function to handle all case perfectly. Search it and you will find many threads on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, can't type string.Its only allowed the numbers

```
<input type="text" min="1" max="5" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required />
```

Comment: This will prevent input from other keys like `backspace`, `enter`, `delete` so not so usable practically since user cant delete the value or edit it. Only option will be up and down button inside the field

Comment: @sanjan it can be edit the value please check it while i am using type="text"

Comment: I want user to give ranges from 0-100

Comment: you change type="number " then give min="1" and max="100" , if submit your form its through the validation error. only valid for 1-100

Comment: <input type="number" min="1" max="100" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required />

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want the user to enter the ranges from 0-100 in a text box. Eg: 20 - 80

Answer (score 3):

Just use input **type="number"**

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" required />
```

as per your requirement for input **type="text"** check the snippet

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-form="myForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="image" min="1" max="5" name="textfrom" required  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
      <div>{{myForm.textfrom.$valid}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No i want it for for sting  <b>type="text"<b>